# Java execute linux script

Tags: java, linux

Evening, i'd like to execute a linux script that is located at /Scripts/copy.sh . I already gave him execute permissions and on java i'm using the following:

```
String tmp = "./Scripts/copy.sh";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       new String[] {"/bin/bash","-c", tmp}
);

p.waitFor();
```

I just can't get it to work, no errors neither exceptions. Any ideas?

Comment: `./Scripts` is not `/Scripts`, which is correct? And does `/Scripts/copy.sh` work if you run it without Java?

Comment: It must be ./Scripts because i'm invoking the script to be executed, this is, according to linux's shell lol. Yes it does work.

Comment: And your java process is starting in the same linux shell folder? "./" is a relative path. What's the result of `pwd`?

Comment: Project file path: /home/angelo/NetBeansProjects/KeyMapper/src and the script /home/angelo/NetBeansProjects/KeyMapper/Scripts/

Comment: try to subscribe to the stdin and stderr stream. You might get more info from them. Also [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) article is great for Runtime.exec() and the pitfalls related to it (like blocking buffers).

Comment: Use absolute path instead of relative path for your script, or make sure you start your java program in /home/angelo/NetBeansProjects/KeyMapper

Answer (score 0):

The script is still running. It just isn't displaying output in the current terminal. Replace it with this:

```
String tmp = "./Scripts/copy.sh";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       new String[] {"/bin/bash","-c", tmp + " >/dev/tty </dev/tty"}
);
p.waitFor();
```

This will pipe stdin and stdout of the process to the controlling terminal (It also allows you to run an interactive console program).